# I need to be able to select more than 1 product for my receipt table (order-detail) SQL DATABASE

Tags: sql, database

I've made a database on a hypothetical company that sells fast food

I want it to track the staff, their shifts, the items, the outlet and the orders but when I made the table for the receipt(order-detail) I've went wrong I want to be able to select more than 1 item as a customer may order more than 1 item but I can't wrap my head round how to fix my database any advice would be appreciated

[This is my Entity Relationship:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jna3.png)

[This is me trying to add a receipt(order-detail) but I can only add 1 product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdVAQ.jpg)

**Thanks to NickW**

[This is my finished result and it seems to work:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4YnF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an order-lineitems table between the order-detail and item tables

Comment: Thanks I felt like I was in front of a brick wall I just couldn't seem to come up with a solution I think it was the equivalent of writers block, thanks again